# Hbase 0.98.0-hadoop2 mvn dependency

Tags: maven, hbase, dependency-management

I am adding hbase jars in my client project using mvn dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
  <artifactId>hbase</artifactId>
  <version>0.98.0-hadoop2</version>
</dependency>
```

However, mvn is not able to find the required version and is giving error. I myself checked at following link but there is no hbase-0.98.0-hadoop2.jar present at that location. Please help

Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hbase/hbase/0.98.0-hadoop2/hbase-0.98.0-hadoop2.jar
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.apache.hbase:hbase:jar:0.98.0-hadoop2' in repository java.net (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
Downloading: https://repository.jboss.org/maven2//org/apache/hbase/hbase/0.98.0-hadoop2/hbase-0.98.0-hadoop2.jar
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.apache.hbase:hbase:jar:0.98.0-hadoop2' in repository jboss (https://repository.jboss.org/maven2/)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dependency definition which you have mentioned has been updated. Use below maven dependency definition instead :-

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
    <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
    <version>0.98.8-hadoop2</version>
</dependency>
```

this will solve your problem.